# GetPlayers not working on server side script

Tags: lua, local, server-side, roblox

I am learning lua making games in Roblox. I have this sample of code that I got from their developer website.

```
Players = game:GetService("Players")
for i, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
    print(player.Name)
end
```

This code works when I paste it in a local script but it doesn't when I paste it in a server side script. I don't get an error, but nothing gets printed. I am wondering why this is, and also what code do I need to use to get all players from a server side script. Thanks

Edit --------------------------------------------------

I have also tried to run this code both on a server side script and a local script:

```
local players = game.Players:GetChildren()

print(typeof(players))
```

When this code is running on a local script, it comes back with: table. I got nothing when I run it on a server side script. Is this normal?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is the worst way to ever explain an issue. does it throw an exception? if yes, what is the message and stack trace? does it return a failure? if so, what? does GetService return a valid players object? is the GetPlayers() result an empty table? does the player.Name have the wrong names? empty names? nil names? is it running but you don't see it printing to stdout? I don't have any experience with roblocks lua programming (i have plenty of lua experience). I'm just trying to explain why "it doesn't work" is the least helpful issue information, never settle on just saying that

Comment: You are right, I'll edit

Comment: Another valuable piece of information to check is where is this Script located? According to (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Script) the Script must be a descendant of the Workspace or ServerScriptStorage. Otherwise it simply won't execute the Script.

Comment: I only tried this with the script a child of workplace and a child of serverservice. Neither work

Comment: It's unusual that nothing is appearing in the output at all for the code sample in the edit. The Script isn't disabled is it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a timing issue.
When you run this as a LocalScript, the flow of the game is :

1. Server starts, number of players = 0
2. Player joins, number of players = 1
3. LocalScript runs - prints out the list of all 1 players

When you run this as a server Script, the flow of the game is :

1. Server starts, number of players = 0
2. Script runs - prints out the list of all 0 players

If you were to modify your example to be something like this:

```
Players = game:GetService("Players")
print(string.format("Listing all %d player names :", #Players:GetPlayers()))
for i, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
    print(i, "- ", player.Name)
end
print("Done listing names")
```

You should expect to see this in the output :

```
Listing all 0 player names :
Done listing names
```

Comment: Hi, I think you might be right, the only way I could make it to work in the end was to wrap the for loop in a PlayerAdded event. Question remains, how to get it to work without doing this?

Comment: @Paul, you need a way to fire this loop after players have joined. What do you want to trigger the behavior? One way to trigger actions from the game into server Scripts are through the use of RemoteEvents (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent). So 1) create a RemoteEvent in the Workspace or ReplicatedStorage. 2) Instead of using the PlayerAdded event in your Script, connect to the RemoteEvent's OnServerEvent. 3) Use another Script or LocalScript to call the RemoteEvent's FireServer() function. This could be when you touch a Part or click a button in a simple gui.