# getPlayers not working on server-side script?

Tags: for-loop, lua, server-side, roblox

Why does this code work on a local script but not a server-side script?

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

for i, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
    print(player.Name)
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetPlayers not working on server side script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59697101/getplayers-not-working-on-server-side-script)

Answer (score 0):

It's a server script, so it runs when the game starts.(before the player joins)
What you might be looking for is the `PlayerAdded` event:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    print(player.Name)
end)
```

It works locally, because the local script would run when the player joins, so there's a player to find.

Or to put in a loop, you would be able to sue the current script, you just need to put it into a loop:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

while true do
    wait(howLongBetween)
    for i, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
        print(player.Name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code executes before there is any player in the game. Consider adding wait().